# Grunt task for making sure you have copyrights on each file

Tags: gruntjs

I need to make sure there's copyrights notice at the beginning of each file.

How can I use grunt to fail my build in case the copyrights statement is missing?

Comment: To the one that voted to close this question due to it being "off topic" - I think this question falls under `practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession`

Comment: why the vote to close? surely it's [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (it's about *software tools commonly used by programmers*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming you are referring to ***.js or *.html** or other similar work files, and not to graphic or binary files.

This can be done, with a `grunt.registerTask` which will:

```
1. loop through all relevant files
2. Read and compare first line to copyright line
3. If different - re-write file but a new first line which will be the copyright info
```

Pretty simple. Again - this will not work on binary files. I wrote this for you but it seems very useful, I might consider adding it as a plugin. Field tested:

run it by `grunt verifyCopyright` and also make sure that if your files are in a different directory your change it, and also if you want to process other files add them to the list as well. **good luck**...

```
 grunt.registerTask('verifyCopyright', function () {

    var fileRead, firstLine, counter = 0, fileExtension, commentWrapper;
    copyrightInfo = 'Copyright by Gilad Peleg @2013';

    //get file extension regex
    var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;

    grunt.log.writeln();

    // read all subdirectories from your modules folder
    grunt.file.expand(
        {filter: 'isFile', cwd: 'public/'},
        ["**/*.js", ['**/*.html']])
        .forEach(function (dir) {
            fileRead = grunt.file.read('public/' + dir).split('\n');
            firstLine = fileRead[0];

            if (firstLine.indexOf(copyrightInfo > -1)) {

                counter++;
                grunt.log.write(dir);
                grunt.log.writeln(" -->doesn't have copyright. Writing it.");

                //need to be careful about:
                //what kind of comment we can add to each type of file. i.e /* <text> */ to js
                fileExtension = re.exec(dir)[1];
                switch (fileExtension) {
                    case 'js':
                        commentWrapper = '/* ' + copyrightInfo + ' */';
                        break;
                    case 'html':
                        commentWrapper = '<!-- ' + copyrightInfo + ' //-->';
                        break;
                    default:
                        commentWrapper = null;
                        grunt.log.writeln('file extension not recognized');
                        break;
                }

                if (commentWrapper) {
                    fileRead.unshift(commentWrapper);
                    fileRead = fileRead.join('\n');
                    grunt.file.write( 'public/' + dir, fileRead);
                }
            }
        });

    grunt.log.ok('Found', counter, 'files without copyright');
})
```

Comment: I have yet to try this but seems like an answer to me. I will give feedback once I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking to see if it's there and failing, why not just have a task that automatically injects it? See [grunt-banner](https://github.com/mattstyles/grunt-banner).

Comment: because I need the files committed with this.

Comment: `it makes no attempt to see if a banner already exists and it is up to the user to ensure that the file should not already contain a banner` - I need the exact opposite. But I might use it in other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thekua/grunt-regex-check could be what you want. You define the regex to check for and if it finds it then the task fails.